# Why won't the plane start?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

I enter a perfectly normal airplane at a perfectly normal airport and I sit down in a perfectly normal seat. However, so long as I am sitting in this seat, the plane will not start. I'm not in the pilots or co-pilot's seat, and as I am a perfectly normal man, I could definitely be in this seat, but apparently not today. I'm not in an emergency aisle Everyone is on board, including the flight attendants, passengers, pilot, and co-pilot. There is nothing obstructing the plane and the runway. But as long as I sit in this particular seat, the plane will not start.

**Why won't the plane start?**

---

**Clarifications:**

> Additionally, the plane is cleared for take off. There is nothing wrong with anything outside of the plane, or with the plane itself. Everyone who is supposed to be in the plane is inside the plane, and no one else is. I'm not a child, and I'm in perfectly good health. The pilot/crew are free to get to wherever they want, and the airline has no seat restrictions. There is no one else in my seat. The airline/airport is not preventing any takeoff.

---

*note:*
This is my first ever puzzle. At this stage, there may be multiple solutions (although, there is only one intended one). The puzzle was originally designed so that the puzzle-solver could ask yes-or-no questions. I tried to answer the most common guesses I had in the problem, but if you have any yes-or-no questions, feel free to comment. <strike>I will answer in-post due to account restrictions.</strike> nvm, I can answer your questions :D

Comment: Is there anyone else in the seat?

Comment: Welcome!  FYI, you should always be able to comment on your own question, but certainly placing clarifications in the post itself is a good idea. Perhaps also mark them as such so that earlier answers still make sense.

Comment: @feelinferrety Good Idea! Sorry, I'm still a bit new to stackexchange :P

Comment: @paste No, there is no one else in the seat.

Comment: Do you have a ticket for this flight?

Comment: @paste Yes, I'm allowed to be in the plane. But I wouldn't necessarily say I have a ticket.

Comment: Is the seat in question inside the plane?

Comment: FYI, at a controlled airport (which is normal for a commercial passenger plane to use) you're not going to get *cleared for takeoff* until the plane's engines are running (i.e. *it's already started*) and has taxied to near the active runway.

Comment: the plane won't start even if I switch to any other seat in the plane ?

Comment: When you say the plane won't *start*, do you mean the plane engines will not turn on or that the plane won't leave the airport.

Comment: -1 and VTC for being far too broad. Almost all of the answers validly answer your question, as it is currently written.

Comment: @Rahul Parashar - Pilot forgot keys at home

Comment: Are you sitting on Pilot seat ?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes.

Comment: @MarchHo Sorry, I tried to adapt it as best I could

Comment: @SGR Both, really. The plane can't move/do anything.

Comment: Why are the clarifications in a spoiler block?

Comment: @reirab Should I unspoiler them? I guess I left them spoiler'd as people could consider them a hint, in a way. (Sorry, I'm still new to this stackxchange)

Comment: You keep using the word 'normal' instead of 'regular' or 'typical'. My first thought was the plane was perpendicular to the ground, which conceivably causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: It's weird how a question an receive tens of votes and still get closed, I vote that this is reopened as the OP has clarified

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're

> the pilot sitting in one of the passengers' seats.

Comment: oh man, i was just about to say it, too ;]

Comment: But OP has mentioned "as long as I sit in this particular seat, the plane will not start."

Comment: @Himanshu Well, the pilot needs to be in his own seat to start the plane.

Comment: But that line indicates if he changes his seat, plane will start. means pilot is at his right position :)

Comment: @Himanshu: No, it just says if he is in THAT seat, the plane won't start. It doesn't say anything about what other seats he can be in for the plane to start.

Comment: Agree to @Himanshu - question indicates one specific seat. Although question does not say anything about other seats, it seems to related to that specific seat which you are occupying.

Comment: @KristapsVilerts: Well, if the pilot is sitting in the specific seat, then he's not sitting in the pilot's seat.

Comment: This is also what I thought after reading the first few lines.

Comment: The question says *"I am a perfectly normal man"* so it sounded like the man is *not* the pilot (or maybe I fell for the "trick")

Comment: @Xen2050. Right. because you have to be a bit crazy (not normal) to be a pilot.

Comment: @Marius That's not exactly what I meant - given *"I'm not in the pilots or co-pilot's seat, and as I am a perfectly normal man"* I read the quote as the guy's not a pilot or co-pilot (maybe not even a passenger).

Comment: @Xen2050 I don't think there's anything abnormal about being a pilot/co-pilot/passenger. If we followed that logic, what would a normal person be? A person who does nothing at all?

Comment: Yes! Nice job figuring it out. :)

Comment: @michal - does really pilot clasifies as *perfectly normal man*? :)

Comment: @KristapsVilerts Yes, he can be the same as you or me. Man being used in the definition of human being, and he is a perfectly normal one. Any other speculation to what "normal" means is subjective, and is used as a device to distract from who I might be. :)

Comment: Is the co-pilot really unable to start the plane by himself? Also, I would say that any seat that the pilot is sitting in is the "pilot's seat".

Comment: @Matt If you were to ask someone where the pilot's seat is in a plane, they'd say in the front or the cockpit. That's the Pilot's Seat. Also, I'd wager that it's against FAA regulations to start the plane with out both pilot and co-pilot in the cockpit.

Comment: @paste Depends on your definition of "can't start," I guess. Certainly, the FO is very capable of starting the engines. I actually don't remember any FAA reg requiring both crew members to be at their station for _the engines to start,_ but I do think they're required to be at their station to begin taxi. However, most airline operating procedures probably require them to be at their station for engine start under most circumstances.

Comment: @reirab I'll defer to you on that one; I was just guessing :) In any case, I assume anyone _can_ start the plane, but they just wouldn't with the pilot acting silly and sitting in a passenger's seat.

Comment: Um, couldn't another pilot fly the plane?

Comment: @RahulParashar: Please don't be rude.

Comment: I am not rude, its just not the kind of puzzle which should be answered like this.

I can make a thousand such puzzles every day. The answer is not good enough, while every other answer just fits quite right/meaningful in its context.

Comment: I am blaming the author of the puzzle not the answerer.

Comment: @RahulParashar: Yes, and you're doing it in a rude way. Comparing the author to a 3-year-old is disrespectful.

Comment: @paste Cloudy, misleading question IMO. On board an airplane, the pilot & co-pilot are probably the 2 people that most stand out as *not normal*, average, regular, or any other similar description. And I'm not sure about commercial airliners, but for a single engine non-commercial plane you don't even need a pilot to start the engine, just someone "competent" enough to turn it off & on, and step on the brake if it starts to move, probably so mechanics & their assistants can get work done without a pilot sitting there, so I'm pretty sure it applies to commercial jets too. (@ Matt too)

Comment: @Xen2050 That's the nature of lateral thinking puzzles, though. They're not meant to be answered outright; they're supposed to be iteratively gleaned through yes-or-no questions. SE isn't really ideal format for them.

Answer (score 13):

You

> are a baggage handler, sitting in a perfectly normal seat, possibly a nice armchair, which has been loaded into the cargo hold. The plane can't take off whilst you are there, but if the seat was in you living room, you'd be fine. You're allowed onto the plane to load the baggage, but don't have a ticket.

Comment: Nice idea, but not the answer I was looking for

Comment: The plane wouldn't have been cleared in this situation.

Answer (score 10):

Plane does not start because

> pilot is sitting by the window and you are blocking him. When you get up, pilot is free to go and he can start the plane! 
>  [image: Layout of new seat layout concept]

**Update**

> Although picture above is from **concept** plane seat layout and does not classifies as *perfectly normal airplane*, most of airplanes have very small amount of seat space, making impossible to get out of windows seat without disturbing neighbor.
>  [image: Regular seat]

Comment: Wait, is this an actual airline cabin setup? What airline is this?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs That is new type of plane seat layout - http://www.businessinsider.com/this-new-airplane-seat-by-zodiac-could-bring-awkwardness-to-a-whole-new-level-2015-7

Comment: hahaha nice idea

Answer (score 10):

Three Answers.
Answer 1.

> You are sitting on the toilet seat and the plane is not allowed to take off.

Answer 2.

> You are sitting in one of the seats the flight attendants use when taking off or landing. Again regulations prohibit you from doing this.

Answer 3.

> You are in a wheelchair aboard the plane.

Comment: Answers 1 & 2 aren't normal seats per se... Answer 3 is reasonable, but again, not normal.

Comment: @michal. I agree with you. The obvious answer was offered by Deusovi. I was trying to think outside the box and get some alternatives out there.

Comment: this is a very open-ended riddle, so its very interesting to see everyone's take on it!

Answer (score 8):

My guess:

> People saying that you are in the pilot's seat or flight attendants...it's exactly the other way!!
>  You are a flight attendant and are in a normal seat, so the flight won't take off until you go to your corresponding seat!!

Reasons:

> I can be in the plane, but do not necessarily have a ticket. Since you are part of the crew...
>  Everyone is on board, including the flight attendants. Since you are one of them...
>  I could definitely be in this seat, but apparently not today. You could sit there any day you are a normal passenger, but not today, today is a workday for you and MUST sit in your flight attendant seat!

EDIT: 2nd Answer

> If first one was wrong, then I have to say air controller. Same reasons apply.

If that's not the good one, not sure what could be xD. Was pretty sure about the first one :(

Comment: I'm not the flight attendant, but close :)

Comment: LoL, I missread your text, I thought it was saying: " I'm not the pilot or co-pilot". So totally threw those options away :S

Answer (score 4):

you are in

> The bathroom toilet seat.

Comment: Not a perfectly normal seat as I meant it. I'll clarify.

Comment: sorry :( i found a toilet seat a perfectly normal seat :/   hmmm will have to rethink.

Comment: @CptEric Next time you go over someone's house and they ask you to take a seat, you should go sit on the toilet :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> you could be dead or drunk.  Both are "perfectly normal" things for a man, but the pilot won't go forward with you in that state today.  if you're dead you have to be stowed, not sitting in the seat.  You could sit there when you're sober or alive, but not today. 
>  Also you could just be a passenger sitting in the wrong seat - as some airplines insist people are correctly seated for take off (so they can identify missing people (or bodies in a crash)).  you don't need to be anyone particular, and you could have had this seat on another day. But today your seat is another seat, so until you stop being annoying and move to your allocated seat for takeoff the pilot can't move onto the runway for taxiing or takeoff...despite having clearance from the tower to do so.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to make use of spoiler tags? You can add a spoiler tag by starting your line with >! and then the rest of your line.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Every answer in these types of questions should really be hidden by a "spoiler"?

Comment: @Xen2050 It is the standard agreed upon by the Puzzling community. Spoiler tags make it so that people who want to think about the solution themselves can do so without being distracted by the answers others have given.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Ok, seemed a little odd with all the "blank" answers, but I guess if the question doesn't take up the a whole page it's easy to see an answer by mistake, and new ones pop up just under the Q too.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll clarify my riddle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because:

> The plane has just arrived, I need to get off the plane so it can start.

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> child, which needs a special children seat with special belts.

I enter a perfectly normal airplane at a perfectly normal airport and I sit down in a perfectly normal seat.

> You entered it with your parents and were sat down by them.

However, so long as I am sitting in this seat, the plane will not start.

> As long as you are not in a special seat that fits your age, the risks are too high, so the pilot/crew are not allowed to start.

I'm not in the pilots or co-pilot's seat, and as I am a perfectly normal man, I could definitely be in this seat, but apparently not today.

> You are in your own 'normal' seat and in the future you are allowed to sit there (becoming older), but not today.

I'm not in an emergency aisle.

> You are in your own 'normal' seat

Everyone is on board, including the flight attendants, passengers, pilot, and co-pilot.

> And your parents.

There is nothing obstructing the plane and the runway. But as long as I sit in this particular seat, the plane will not start.

> Give this kid finally his special seat, so we can get this plane in the air...

Yes, I am allowed to be in the plane. However, no, I do not necessarily have a ticket.

> Some airlines will let the child on board for free, so there is no need for a ticket

Comment: it is a pretty logic answer! I thought about it but I didn't like it to be the right one :/

Comment: Good logic, I guess I should have clarified more that I was a man and not a child.

Comment: Side note: Children are NOT required to be in a child seat on board aircraft. In fact, they are VERY difficult to manage (tight spaces, time constraints), and unless it is built to be secured by lap belt only, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are

> The pilot's ex. He/She(The pilot) doesn't want you to be onboard, So the pilot won't start the plane unless you get out of the plane.

Another thought.

> You are in the toilet seat, with someone in the toilet the flight won't take off.

Comment: Just read your answer. I swear I read it after I've written my answer. :)

Comment: No probs man :)

Answer (score 1):

> You're one of the ground crew. You can come on to the plane to do tasks/whatever, but there's something you need to do outside before the plane can take off.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> an airport ground staff sitting in passenger seat

Answer (score -1):

You:

> Must be sitting in the wrong chair and refuse to move

Answer (score -4):

you are

> the president, in Air Force One, sitting in a meeting room chair

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted so much, but the Air Force One isn't your typical plane.